# Java - Logback to display status of run (passed / failed)

Tags: java, selenium, logback, slf4j

I am using Logback in my Selenium Webdriver project and I'm trying to find a way to log the status (whether the test passed or failed) right at the end of the test, so when looking through the logs you know which test has failed.

I've got an `afterMethod` where I currently log "**testGoogleWebsite has finished**", but want to get "**testGoogleWebsite has failed**" or "**testGoogleWebsite has passed**".

My Test:

```
@Test
 public void testGoogleWebsite() {
    openGoogleWebsite();
    searchForStackOverflow();
    clickOnStackOverflowLink();
}


@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(Method method){
    LOG.debug(method.getName() + " has finished");
}
```

My logback file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="target/Logs" />

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>

    <logger name="com.test" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: So, you use TestNG, right? Because this should be the most relevant tag for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(ITestResult result)
{

    String tcName = result.getName();
    if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS)
    {

        //Do something here
        LOG.debug(tcName  + " has passed");
    }

    else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
    {
         //Do something here
        LOG.debug(tcName  + " has failed");

    }

     else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP ){

       LOG.debug(tcName  + " has skipped");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I've seen `@AfterMethod`, I suppose that you use **TestNG**.

Then, you can try:

```
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(ITestResult result) {
   String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
   if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
       LOG.debug(methodName + " has failed");
   } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
       LOG.debug(methodName + " has passed");
   }       
}
```